# Printing pdf with Octave and gnuplot

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, octave

There seems to be a problem with my method of exporting plots as .pdf files when using `gnuplot` in `Octave`. The process lasts a long time and even after aborting it the resulting (corrupted) file is hundreds of MBs in size. The same operation works fine when using fltk.

As an example:

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
%graphics_toolkit fltk
hist(rand(1,1000))
print test -dpdf
```

I tried using `-dpdf` and `-dpdfwrite` to no avail. Exporting to other formats, such as .png and .eps works as expected.

Comment: It works under linux, with octave 3.8.2. Which version are you using ? Windows or linux ?

Comment: @ederag Thank you for testing it. I'm using Octave 3.6.4 for Windows (on Win 7). Do you think this is something that had been fixed in subsequent versions?

Comment: @Fato39 Why don't you just try Octave octave-4.0.0-rc3-installer.exe from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/octave/? If the error is still there, please file a bugreport

Comment: Thank you very much, @Andy! It works well with this version, indeed. I was using an MXE build and wasn't aware more recent builds are available for Windows. (Either the [Wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows) does not mention this or it's not clear enough for me on this point.)

Comment: @Fato39 Well... it's a release candiate and not a release. I guess it will take some weeks until you'll find the 4.0.0 release announcement. Btw, this is also a MXE build.